# How do I get rid of my duplicate GRUB entries? (Ubuntu 12.10, RAID1)

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mdadm, grub, grub2

I have a Dell R300 machine running Ubuntu 12.10:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:    12.10
Codename:   quantal

$ uname -a
Linux green 3.2.0-32-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 26 21:33:09 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have RAID1 set up, with three partitions (/boot, /swap and everything else):

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md2 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      484386304 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      3903680 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      96256 blocks [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>

# mount
/dev/md2 on / type ext3 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid)
/dev/md0 on /boot type ext3 (rw,noatime)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid)
```

My GRUB boot menu has many duplicate entries:
[image: GRUB level 1]

Here's what's inside one of them:
[image: GRUB level 2]

How do I clean up/simplify this?

Answer (score 0):

You would edit the /boot/grub/menu.lst file for Grub, [these directions](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/clean-up-ubuntu-grub-boot-menu-after-upgrades/) may be of use.
You would not edit the main file /etc/default/grub.cfg for Grub2, but [these directions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) may be of use.

Read this:

"GRUB 2 builds its menu (grub.cfg) by running scripts found in the /etc/grub.d/folder and the settings in the /etc/default/grub file. This file is recreated automatically whenever the update-grub command is run. This command activates scripts which by default determine the status of the current Ubuntu OS and search the system for other operating systems which, if found, are added to the GRUB 2 menu."

and

"Only executable files generate output to grub.cfg during execution of update-grub. By default the files in the /etc/grub.d folder are executable. "

I hope this is of help, good luck!

Comment: `menu.lst` is for GRUB1, not GRUB2.

Comment: didn't see the image til now sorry

Comment: I've tried `update-grub`. It's what's giving me the results I have now.